# Filtering DataFrame Columns by Specific Value in Row

Tags: python, dataframe

I had a small question regarding the possibility to filter a Dataframe in Python.
The Dataframe has various rows containing strings and integers. The row of interest is called “numbervalues” which contains numbers from 1 until 30, sometimes containing multiple entries (i.e. not only “1” but also “1+2” or "1;2"). I want to filter for the columns containing the number “5” in the row. I tried various lines of code such as

df[df[“numbervalues”].astype(str).str.contains(“5”)]

or

df[df[“numbervalues”] == “5”]

The problem is that the first option is too inclusive / broad as it also includes numbers such as “15” which I don’t want to select. The second option however is too selective, as it does not catch the rows that have multiple values such as “5+3” or "5;9"
I also thought about dropping values such as “15” and “25” to exclude these sets, but some rows contain “5+15” thus I would also be dropping relevant values from my dataset.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to do that:

```
df.loc[df["numbervalues"].str.contains(r'\b5\b')]
```